# JAX-WS webservice run when executing mvn:tomcat7:run but fails when installing on actual tomcat server

Tags: java, web-services, maven, jax-ws, tomcat7

I have a multi module webservice that is failing to run under a standard tomcat7 server but will execute without issue within the embedded tomcat server that maven supplies using mvn tomact7:run.  How are the two different?  I'm assuming it's a classpath issue but any help would be greatly appreciated.  Here's a dump of the fail.

```
2013-11-21 10:34:32,071]DEBUG   189[localhost-startStop-1] - org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.initHandlerMappings(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:133) - Ignoring handler [org.springframework.ws.config.WebServicesNamespaceHandler]: problem with class file or dependent class
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.isPresent(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Z
    at org.springframework.ws.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.<clinit>(AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java:60)
    at org.springframework.ws.config.WebServicesNamespaceHandler.init(WebServicesNamespaceHandler.java:31)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.initHandlerMappings(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.<init>(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:96)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.<init>(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:82)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.createDefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:530)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.createReaderContext(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:499)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:407)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:357)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:126)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:91)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.java:156)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:246)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:184)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1628)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
[2013-11-21 10:34:32,083]DEBUG   201[localhost-startStop-1] - org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.initHandlerMappings(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:133) - Ignoring handler [org.springframework.context.config.ContextNamespaceHandler]: problem with class file or dependent class
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.isPresent(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Z
    at org.springframework.context.config.MBeanServerBeanDefinitionParser.<clinit>(MBeanServerBeanDefinitionParser.java:51)
    at org.springframework.context.config.ContextNamespaceHandler.init(ContextNamespaceHandler.java:41)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.initHandlerMappings(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.<init>(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:96)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.<init>(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:82)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.createDefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:530)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.createReaderContext(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:499)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:407)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:357)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:126)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:91)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.java:156)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:246)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:184)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1628)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
[2013-11-21 10:34:32,088]DEBUG   206[localhost-startStop-1] - org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.initHandlerMappings(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:133) - Ignoring handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.config.MvcNamespaceHandler]: problem with class file or dependent class
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.isPresent(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Z
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.<clinit>(AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java:79)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.MvcNamespaceHandler.init(MvcNamespaceHandler.java:32)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.initHandlerMappings(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.<init>(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:96)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.<init>(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:82)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.createDefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:530)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.createReaderContext(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:499)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:407)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:357)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:126)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:91)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.java:156)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:246)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:184)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1628)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
[2013-11-21 10:34:32,089]DEBUG   207[localhost-startStop-1] - org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:83) - Loading bean definitions
[2013-11-21 10:34:32,098]DEBUG   216[localhost-startStop-1] - org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2c.XBeanNamespaceHandler.loadResource(XBeanNamespaceHandler.java:739) - Could not find resource: META-INF/services/org/apache/xbean/spring/http/jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet/binding
[2013-11-21 10:34:32,103]DEBUG   221[localhost-startStop-1] - org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseBeanDefinitionElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:427) - Neither XML 'id' nor 'name' specified - using generated bean name [com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.SpringBinding]
[2013-11-21 10:34:32,108]DEBUG   226[localhost-startStop-1] - org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2c.XBeanNamespaceHandler.loadResource(XBeanNamespaceHandler.java:739) - Could not find resource: META-INF/services/org/apache/xbean/spring/http/jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core/service
[2013-11-21 10:34:32,108]DEBUG   226[localhost-startStop-1] - org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseBeanDefinitionElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:427) - Neither XML 'id' nor 'name' specified - using generated bean name [org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.spring.SpringService]
[2013-11-21 10:34:32,136]DEBUG   254[localhost-startStop-1] - org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:144) - Loaded 6 bean definitions from location pattern [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
[2013-11-21 10:34:32,137]DEBUG   255[localhost-startStop-1] - org.springframework.core.CollectionFactory.createLinkedSetIfPossible(CollectionFactory.java:98) - Creating [java.util.LinkedHashSet]
[2013-11-21 10:34:32,138] INFO   256[localhost-startStop-1] - org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:347) - Loading XML bean definitions from URL [jar:file:/Users/aperkins/Maven/internalservices/lcm/internalservices-lcm/target/internalservices-lcm-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/internalservices-handler-1.0-20131114.140213-297.jar!/handler-context.xml]
[2013-11-21 10:34:32,139]DEBUG   257[localhost-startStop-1] - org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:74) - Using JAXP provider [com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl]
[2013-11-21 10:34:32,140]DEBUG   258[localhost-startStop-1] - org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DelegatingEntityResolver.resolveEntity(DelegatingEntityResolver.java:99) - Attempting to resolve XML Schema [http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd] using [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver]
[2013-11-21 10:34:32,157]DEBUG   275[localhost-startStop-1] - org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.initHandlerMappings(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:110) - Loaded mappings [{http://www.springframework.org/schema/task=org.springframework.scheduling.config.TaskNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/p=org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.SimplePropertyNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config=org.springframework.webflow.config.WebFlowConfigNamespaceHandler, http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet=org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2.XBeanNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang=org.springframework.scripting.config.LangNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util=org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.UtilNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/c=org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.SimpleConstructorNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee=org.springframework.ejb.config.JeeNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm=org.springframework.oxm.config.OxmNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx=org.springframework.transaction.config.TxNamespaceHandler, http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core=org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2.XBeanNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services=org.springframework.ws.config.WebServicesNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc=org.springframework.jdbc.config.JdbcNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop=org.springframework.aop.config.AopNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context=org.springframework.context.config.ContextNamespaceHandler, http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/local-transport=org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2.XBeanNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache=org.springframework.cache.config.CacheNamespaceHandler, http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc=org.springframework.web.servlet.config.MvcNamespaceHandler}]
[2013-11-21 10:34:32,157]DEBUG   275[localhost-startStop-1] - org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.isPresent(ClassUtils.java:128) - Class [groovy.lang.GroovyObject] or one of its dependencies is not present: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.lang.GroovyObject
[2013-11-21 10:34:32,158]DEBUG   276[localhost-startStop-1] - org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.isPresent(ClassUtils.java:128) - Class [org.jruby.IRuby] or one of its dependencies is not present: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jruby.IRuby
[2013-11-21 10:34:32,159]DEBUG   277[localhost-startStop-1] - org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.isPresent(ClassUtils.java:128) - Class [bsh.Interpreter] or one of its dependencies is not present: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bsh.Interpreter
[2013-11-21 10:34:32,159]DEBUG   277[localhost-startStop-1] - org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.initHandlerMappings(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:133) - Ignoring handler [org.springframework.ws.config.WebServicesNamespaceHandler]: problem with class file or dependent class
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.ws.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser
    at org.springframework.ws.config.WebServicesNamespaceHandler.init(WebServicesNamespaceHandler.java:31)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.initHandlerMappings(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.<init>(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:96)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.<init>(DefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver.java:82)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.createDefaultNamespaceHandlerResolver(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:530)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.createReaderContext(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:499)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:407)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:357)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:126)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:91)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.java:156)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:246)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:184)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1628)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you've got duplicate JARs or different versions on the classpath? I'd make sure you've only got the one most upto date one and try it again.